# How to Convert a column having one timestamp to another timestamp in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, timestamp, azure-data-factory

I have column **ABC** where timestamp is of format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:SS (11/04/2020 1:17:40).I want to create another column **ABC_NEW** with same data as old column but with different timestamp 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS'.I tried doing in azure data factory derived column using

toTimestamp(column_name,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS') but it did not work it is coming as NULL. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a 2-step process. You first need to tell ADF what each field in your timestamp column represents, then you can use string conversions to manipulate that timestamp into the output string as you like:

toString(toTimestamp('11/04/2020 1:17:40','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS')

Comment: Hi, @Mark Kromer, I've tried this answer but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Copy & paste my code above into a Derived Column and refresh the data preview. You should see the result you are looking for. Now, replace my string literal ''11/04/2020 1:17:40' with column_name.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Kromer, it works well now. It maybe date format problem of my csv file.

Answer (score 2):

Data Factory doesn't support date format 'dd/mm/yyyy', we can not convert it to 'YYYY-MM-DD' directly.
I use **DerivedColumn** to generate a new column **ABC_NEW** from origin column **DateTime** and enter the expression bellow：

```
toTimestamp(concat(split(substring(DateTime,1, 10), '/')[3], '-',split(substring(DateTime,1, 10), '/')[2],'-',split(substring(DateTime,1, 10), '/')[1],substring(DateTime,11, length(DateTime))))
```

[image]

The result shows:

[image]

Comment: Much simpler: toString(toTimestamp('11/04/2020 1:17:40','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS')

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick which was a blocker for me, but try this-

1. Go to sink
2. Mapping
3. Click on output format
4. Select the data format or time format you prefer to store the data into the sink.