# Mapping Data Flow Common Data Model source connector datetime/timestamp columns nullified?

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are using Azure Data Factory Mapping data flow to read from Common Data Model (model.json).

We use dynamic pattern – where Entity is parameterised and we do not project any columns and we have selected `Allow schema drift.`

**Problem: We are having issue with “Source” in mapping data flow (Source Type is Common Data Model). All the datetime/timestamp columns are read as null in source activity.**

We also tried in projection tab `Infer drifted column types` where we provide a format for timestamp columns, However, it satisfies only certain timestamp columns - since in the source each datetime column has different timestamp format.

```
11/20/2020 12:45:01 PM
2020-11-20T03:18:45Z
2018-01-03T07:24:20.0000000+00:00
```

**Question: How to prevent datetime columns becoming null? Ideally, we do not want Mapping Data Flow to typecast any columns - is there a way to just read all columns as string?**

#### Some screenshots

In Projection tab - we do not specify schema - to allow schema drift and to dynamically load more than 1 entities.
[image]

In Data Preview tab

`ModifiedOn, SinkCreatedOn, SinkModifiedOn` - all these are system columns and will definitely have values in it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This seems to be an incompatible date format. Is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491065/how-to-convert-a-column-having-one-timestamp-to-another-timestamp-in-azure-data/63501233#63501233) helpful for you?

Comment: @jJoseph No, that question and the answer isn't helpful because, the problem is in the source step itself - the CDM inline dataset while reading the data nullifies datetime/timestamp columns - the problem is not further down flow is at the source itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved on a separate conversation with Azure Data Factory team.

Firstly there is no way to 'stringfy' all the columns in Source, because CDM connector gets its metadata from model.json (if needed this file can be manipulated, however not ideal for my scenario).

To solve datetime/timestamp columns becoming null - under Projection tab we need to select `Infer drifted column types` and then you can add "multiple" time formats that you expect to come from CDM. You can either select from dropdown - if your particular datetime format is not listed in the dropdown (which was my case) then you can edit the code behind the data flow (i.e. data flow script), to add your format (see second screenshot).

[image]

[image]